# Could Cylon reincarnation be considered a form of Lamarckian evolution?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, cylon, battlestar-galactica-2004

In the re-imagined series, Cylons have reincarnation technology which allows them to be reborn after death. Could this be considered a form of [Lamarckian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamarckism) evolution? I realize that they're technically not passing their adaptations to their 'children', but if we consider their reborn self as a 'child' it might work.

Comment: Considering Lamarck never used this idea It's not sensible to say it. Lamarck thought that animals evolved into better forms over time, but NOY through inherited charcteristics, and could not evolve into other forms; Basically, if tehy had been around, he;'d have compared it to an elevator, animals move up ( Increase complexity and fitness) while staying fixed in form ( On the same step). Acquired characteristics being passed on was the idea of Comte de Buffon and Lamarck simply found no better idea.

Answer (score 6):

The Cylon version of reincarnation is more like putting on a new shirt after the one your are currently wearing falls apart. If being reborn gave the Cylons an automatic upgrade (cf. the Borg adapting to attacks which succeed against them), this might be more in line with Lamarck.

Answer (score 3):

Evolution, whether Lamarckian or Darwinian, would require that its direction and course be determined by the blind forces of an external environment, without any purpose. Cylon *evolution* in that sense is not even evolution, because it is a conscious and purposeful process that is implemented according to *a plan*.